# how can i solve the error: operator -: nonconformant arguments

Tags: matlab, octave

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2RZK.jpg)

this is the problem that is about digital signal
professor does not want let me use for function
so i tried using sum function
this is what i tried:

```
>> n = -10:10;k = -5:5;x = sum(exp(-abs(k)) .* ((n-2*k)==0));
```

[error: operator -: nonconformant arguments][3] (op1 is 1x21, op2 is 1x11)

i know why it makes error but i don't know how to sum with two variables...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
>>  n = -10:10;>>  k = -5:5;>>  x = exp((-abs(k))) * ((n-2*k')==0);>> stem(n,x,'filled');
```